# Kotlin No ejecuta ContextCompat

Tags: kotlin

Me podrían ayudar con el siguiente código, no consigo que se ejecute:

- tv_option_one.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg) -----> Esta colorea de verde la opcion selecionada
- Se "salta" la instruccion anterior y ejecuta defaultColors() ---- > Esta debe colorear la respuesta de la siguiente pregunta del color por defecto (blanco.
- He intentado introducir un sleep a la funcion defaultColors() para ver si muestra el color verde pero tampoco lo hace.
- Si borro la funcion defaultColors()  el color verde sí se muestra, pero permanece en la siguiente pregunta.

Alguna idea?? gracias.

```
 class QuestionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        var quizzes: MutableList<Quiz>? = null
        var contadorPregunta = 0
        var questions: MutableMap<String, Question>? = null
    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question)

    // VISUALIZACION PREGUNTAS
    private fun bindViews() {
        if (contadorPregunta == questions!!.size) { // last question
            Toast.makeText(this, "HAS COMPLETADO TODAS LAS PREGUNTAS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        else{
            defaultColors()
        }

        val pregunta = indicePreguntas[contadorPregunta]
        val question = questions!!["question$pregunta"]
        question?.let {
            tvDescription.text = it.description
            tv_option_one.text = it.option1
            tv_option_two.text = it.option2
            tv_option_three.text = it.option3
            tv_option_four.text = it.option4
            val respuesta = it.answer

            tv_option_one.setOnClickListener {
                if (tv_option_one.text == respuesta) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "RESPUESTA CORRECTA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    tv_option_one.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)
                    respuestaCorrecta()
                } else {
                    tv_option_one.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.wrong_option_border_bg)
                    respuestaFallada()
                }

            }
            tv_option_two.setOnClickListener {

                if (tv_option_two.text == respuesta) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "RESPUESTA CORRECTA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    tv_option_two.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)
                    respuestaCorrecta()
                } else {
                    tv_option_two.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.wrong_option_border_bg)
                    respuestaFallada()

                }
            }
            tv_option_three.setOnClickListener {

                if (tv_option_three.text == respuesta) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "RESPUESTA CORRECTA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    tv_option_three.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)
                    contadorPregunta++
                    indicePreguntas[contadorPregunta]
                } else {
                    tv_option_three.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.wrong_option_border_bg)
                    respuestaFallada()

                }
            }
            tv_option_four.setOnClickListener {

                if (tv_option_four.text == respuesta) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "RESPUESTA CORRECTA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    tv_option_four.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)
                } else {
                    tv_option_four.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.wrong_option_border_bg)
                    respuestaFallada()

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun defaultColors() {
        tv_option_one.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.default_option_border_bg)
        tv_option_two.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.default_option_border_bg)
        tv_option_three.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.default_option_border_bg)
        tv_option_four.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.default_option_border_bg)
        ivAcierto.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

    }

    private fun respuestaCorrecta() {
        // Ver animacion
        ivAcierto.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        ivAcierto.animate().apply {
            duration=1000
            rotationYBy(1400f)
        }.start()
        contadorPregunta++
        indicePreguntas[contadorPregunta]
        Thread.sleep(2_000)
        bindViews()
    }

    private fun respuestaFallada() {
        //Thread.sleep(1_000)
        // FALLO EN EL TEST
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_one_style_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.dialog_one_style_message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_one_style_positive_btn) { view, _ ->
                view.dismiss()
                val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
                val json = Gson().toJson(quizzes!![0])
                intent.putExtra("QUIZ", json)

                startActivity(intent)
            }
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create()
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si que esta actuando; Por lo que dices, si eliminas defaultColors() se ve en color verde quiere decir que si que actua.
la solución mas simple es cambiar el color antes de mostrar el toast (cambia el orden de las lineas)

```
Toast.makeText(this, "RESPUESTA CORRECTA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
tv_option_one.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)
```

por:

```
tv_option_one.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)
Toast.makeText(this, "RESPUESTA CORRECTA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```